# Debye–Waller factors for tin(IV) oxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, crystallography

How I could find the bulk Debye–Waller factor for tetragonal rutile type $\ce{SnO2}$ at room temperature?

I have been doing some online digging with no luck. If anyone has a reference I could use that would be awesome.

Comment: I'm sure that typical values are known for Sn and O atoms in lots of structures. Looking online is v. v.  limited, you need to properly search the literature :)